# CakePHP 2.0 Jquery Autocomplete / Autosuggest

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, autocomplete, autosuggest

I'm new to both Cake & Ajax/Jquery.

I'm trying to get an autocomplete / autosuggest working in CakePHP 2.0 but everything I find is either for 1.3 or not for Cake at all and I don't know what to do to get it working properly.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Exact Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206822/autocomplete-cakephp-2-0